# Retrieve google+ user info from User authenticated in a GAE

Tags: android, google-app-engine, authentication, google-api

Maybe I'm not really clear how Google APIs and OAuth2 are working, but I can't extract user profile info using the Google+ API client library. What I'm trying to do is to log in to my GAE project with an android client, then from the backend retrieve some info about the user profile (firstname and lastname). Is that possibile? I tried to use the keyword "me" in my api call but I think that is not the right route since what the api call returns is only my e-mail and all the other field are blank; I know that they are all filled in in my profile. Is this because I am on the dev server?

Here is my function to retrieve the user profile:

```
private Person retrieveUserInfo(User user) throws IOException, GeneralSecurityException{
    // Set up the HTTP transport and JSON factory
    HttpTransport httpTransport = GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport();
    JacksonFactory jsonFactory = JacksonFactory.getDefaultInstance();

    GoogleCredential credential = new GoogleCredential.Builder().setTransport(httpTransport)
            .setJsonFactory(jsonFactory)
            .setServiceAccountId("146433070678-dpj18aug5amtqqfqcnmnco4lne91uii5@developer.gserviceaccount.com")
            .setServiceAccountScopes(Collections.singleton(PlusScopes.USERINFO_PROFILE))
            .setServiceAccountPrivateKeyFromP12File(new File("secretkey.p12"))
            .build();


    // Set up the main Google+ class
    Plus plus = new Plus.Builder(httpTransport, jsonFactory, credential)
        .setApplicationName("no_app_id")
        .build();

    // Make a request to access your profile and display it to console
    Person profile = plus.people().get("me").execute();
    return profile;
}
```

I would appreciate any hints about accessing user details from a GAE backend. Thanks.